# Details regarding getting a French Schengen visa

Tags: visas, france, schengen, indian-citizens

I am an Indian, studying in USA. I need to go to France this summer for a conference. Can I apply for a French visa from India (I will be going back to India first in the summer)?

Amongst the documents they ask for at the French consulate in India, is a letter from an Indian employer. My employer is an US university.

I pay tax in the US as well. Does that mean I have to get a visa from the French consulate in USA?

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to apply for the visa from either India (since I assume that's the passport you have) or the US (since you live there), as long as you have all the documents. You say that you're studying there, so you don't need a letter from your *employer* but just a letter from your university confirming your status as a student.