# Applying for Schengen visa from India (working remotely for a US university)

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, france

I am working as a scientist for an US university and I have been invited to attend a conference in France. However, I am working remotely from India to take care of family responsibilities for the last one month. I am not going back to the US before the conference and I plan to leave for France from India. Will I be able to apply for Schengen visa with the France Consulate General in India? I am an Indian citizen and hold an Indian passport. France is my main destination country.

I have read these question posted a long time ago. An answer in one of these say I need to be in India for 6 months to apply from India. Will someone be able to give me an updated answer? Help much appreciated.

1. [Applying for Schengen visa from India for a person working in USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35087/applying-for-schengen-visa-from-india-for-a-person-working-in-usa)
2. [Details regarding getting a French Schengen visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16851/details-regarding-getting-a-french-schengen-visa)

Update on 11 Aug 2023:

Following suggestions from this forum I applied for my Schengen visa with the France Consulate General on 7 Aug. The visa was delivered on 11 Aug. (For the ones interested: I clearly mentioned my situation in the cover letter that I have been allowed to work from home by my employer to take care of family responsibilities. My employer also mentioned the same in their support letter.)

Comment: I believe the answers are still correct. For questions of applicable consulates, you are a resident of the US, currently visiting in India. If possible, you should apply from the US, otherwise you need to explain clearly why you cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are an Indian citizen with a valid passport, and have current residence proof- house ownership papers/ Aadhar card/ rent agreement, then you should have no problem applying from India at all. It's a standard procedure. There are no barriers to Indian citizens applying from India. Only in special cases do they request even the residence proof.